# How can I change the converter for SVGs previews in LyX?

Tags: lyx, linux, svg

I've been using SVG files in my LyX documents, on Arch Linux (LyX 2.1.1), but found that when converting to PDF, the default `rsvg-convert` does a poor job, with many artifacts (e.g. lost text, lost bitmaps, random lines, moved text). Hence, I've changed the converter, by going to `Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters` and using the `inkscape` converter instead, following the instructions [here](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/UseInkscapeSVGImages).

However, I find that the instant previews of the SVGs within LyX itself still uses `rsvg-convert`, with all the artifacts present. Is there a way to change the preview converter that LyX uses?

Comment: Does the information here help? http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/UseInkscapeSVGImages

Comment: Also note that from what I understand you are not "embedding" SVG files in your LyX document. So if you send your LyX document to someone, you need to send your SVG files as well. If I'm wrong, can you please explain how you do the embedding?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that I followed the main body of your link to change to using `inkscape` as the converter. You are also correct; I used the word "embed" incorrectly. I've edited to reflect this. (Also, I noticed that there was a section, `hints > preview` in the link. However, this seems like a draconian fix, if it does work.)

Comment: thanks for the corrections and extra information. I hope someone comes along who can help.

Comment: If you installed inkscape after LyX, did you go to Tools > Reconfigure in LyX after, and then restart LyX?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, I think so. I did it again, just in case, but the previews are still broken. Thanks for your continued suggestions.

Comment: OK. You might want to try starting LyX from the terminal with `lyx -dbg graphics yourfile.lyx`. Then look at the output in the terminal. I'm guessing the problem is that the inkscape converter isn't being called. Also I find it strange that you had to change the converter yourself. LyX should have done this automatically if it found it. Can you back up your home directory (usually `~/.lyx`), then delete it, then restart LyX from the terminal. Then in the terminal output look for "+checking for "inkscape"...  yes". Do you see it? Or does it say "no" ? Which distro do you use? Which LyX version?

Comment: @scottkosty I'm not sure if you understand exactly. Previously, LyX was set up automatically with `rsvg-convert`. However, I found PDF generation to be extremely buggy. Hence, I changed LyX to use `inkscape` as the converter instead. I can confirm that this works as expected, as generated PDFs now look perfect. Further, I can change the inkscape converter options (e.g. `export-area-drawing` vs. `export-area-page`) and confirm that these are reflected in generated PDFs. I did try starting LyX in debug mode, but found not reference to Inkscape. I've updated the question with versions.

Comment: When you run Tools > Reconfigure, this is when LyX can try to detect if it finds inkscape. If it thinks it can't find inkscape, this could explain the problem you're saying. That's why I'm curious in seeing what the output of the line "+checking for inkscape ..." is. Note that LyX's converters are not just used for PDF output but also for LyX rendering.

Comment: Ah okay. I moved `~/.lyx` and I saw `+checking for "inkscape"...  yes`. Indeed, the SVG viewer and editor are set up as `inkscape` by default for me.

Comment: OK, well I guess that's good (but doesn't tell us what the problem is). I'm out of ideas. You might want to email lyx-users@lists.lyx.org. If you find a solution, please post back here.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for the help @scottkosty.